# How to add vertical lines and text to time series plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, autoplot

I have some time series data and used `autoplot` function in R to plot my time series. I would like add vertical lines to the plot and text. For example, a line between 2003-2010 with text "train data", 2010-2015 "test" data and 2015- 2018 "predictions". I did it in ordinary R plot, but it is not fancy. I would like to do it with `ggplot` or `autoplot`. My code is as follows.

```
data <- runif(180,100,1000)
ts.data <- ts(data, frequency = 12, start = c(2003,1))
autoplot(ts.data, xlab="Year", ylab="Number of Tourists")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `ggplot2` itself to get it done:

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- runif(180,100,1000)
ts.data <- ts(data, frequency = 12, start = c(2003,1))
autoplot(ts.data, xlab="Year", ylab="Number of Tourists") +
  geom_vline(xintercept = as.Date(c("2003-01-01", "2010-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2018-01-01") ), color = "blue")+
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2007-01-01"), y = 1020, label="train data"))+
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2013-01-01"),  y = 1020, label="test"))+
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2016-07-01"),  y = 1020, label="predictions"))
```

[image]

I understand you asked about adding vertical lines, just wonder if it is better to use horizontal lines:

```
autoplot(ts.data, xlab="Year", ylab="Number of Tourists") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2003-01-01") , y = 1000, xend = as.Date("2010-01-01"), yend = 1000), color = "red") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2010-01-01") , y = 1000, xend = as.Date("2015-01-01"), yend = 1000), color = "blue") +
  geom_segment(aes(x = as.Date("2015-01-01") , y = 1000, xend = as.Date("2018-01-01"), yend = 1000), color = "green") +
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2007-01-01"), y = 1020, label="train data"), color = "red")+
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2013-01-01"),  y = 1020, label="test"), color = "blue")+
  geom_text(aes(x = as.Date("2017-01-01"),  y = 1020, label="predictions"), color="green")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can we change the text font? I think it is bold and does not look good.

Comment: Yes, definitely. You can change font with `geom_text(..., family =?, fontface =?,  size = ?)`. check `geom_text()` document for details.

Comment: the reason why both segment and text are "bold" is that they are being drawn as many times as the data frame has rows. Better to use `annotate(geom = "text(or:segment)")` instead

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `geomtextpath` package with `geom_textvline` to add vertical lines with labels to `autoplot` since it is a ggplot object. You have to make sure your `xintercept` is the right number because your data is in dates. Here is some reproducible code:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
library(geomtextpath)
autoplot(ts.data, xlab="Year", ylab="Number of Tourists") +
  geom_textvline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date(c("2005-01-01"))),
                 label = "train data", vjust = 1.3, col = "blue") +
  geom_textvline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date(c("2012-01-01"))),
                 label = "test data", vjust = 1.3, col = "blue") +
  geom_textvline(xintercept = as.numeric(as.Date(c("2017-01-01"))),
                 label = "Predictions", vjust = 1.3, col = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>